# Count the records of a collection until a documents record is found

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection called *UserSubmissions* which has the following documents:

1. Choice - Stores the choice the user has input, data is only between A or B
2. Status - Stores the status of the users input whether it was correct or wrong. Data is stored as "Correct" and "Wrong".
3. Date - Stores the date of the submission
4. UserID - The ID of the user logged into the app
5. QuestionID - The ID of the question the user is answering

On the whole, this collection stores submissions of all the users that are logged in with their submissions to different questions and the status for each submission.

I want to count the number of consecutive answers a user has given upto 6 questions.

This is what I have tried in my Meteor App:

```
var total = UserSubmissions.find({UserID: userid}).count();
        var count = 0;
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ ) {
            if ( UserSubmissions.find({UserID: userid}, { sort: {Date: -1}}).fetch()[abs(total - 1 - i)].Status == "Correct") {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Tried using a helper function but it did not work. Not sure where am I wrong. And Mongo might have a built in query function that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to count something "consecutively" without an order. I think you want to use the `Date`? If so, I'd write a function for counting the current streak of consecutive answers like so (using shell notation since I'm not familiar with Meteor)

```
function streak(userid) {
    var lastWrong = db.UserSubmissions.find({ "UserID" : userid, "Status" : "Wrong" }).sort({ "Date" : -1 }).limit(1).toArray()
    if (lastWrong.length === 0) // user has never been wrong!
        return db.UserSubmissions.count({ "UserID" : userid })
    var lastWrongDate = lastWrong[0].Date
    return db.UserSubmissions.count({ "UserID" : userid, "Date" : { "$gt" : lastWrongDate } })
}
```

Comment: Even though this did not help me precisely, but the logic did help me solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make it even more concise, try this:

```
var total = UserSubmissions.find(
  {UserID: userid, Status: "Correct"},
  {limit:5}
).count();
```

Comment: This won't give the consecutive count of correct answers, it will give the count of correct's in the top 5 records.

Comment: I did find this on the internets: http://tiku.io/questions/1115403/find-count-of-maximum-consecutive-records-based-on-one-field-in-mongodb-query

Comment: wdberkeley has solved my problem sort of. Thanks for the support :)